# Change #define value in menu in C Programming Language

Tags: c, constants

I'm creating a game project which allow user to choose the game size (2x2, 3x3, 4x4 etc) using the menu. Currently the game size variable is being declared under #define aka constant. Do i have to make the game size variable to global? If so, how?

Please give me some guidance on how to do it. I'm still a beginner to C Programming Language.

Comment: A macro (`#define` token) is just text that will be substituted into the code before compilation. It becomes an immutable literal value.

However I suspect that since it's a macro, it's being used in a way that isn't easily convertible to a variable that resides in memory and can be changed.

You question is quite too broad to be answer on SO. Since it depends on the actual code you are referring (which we don't have) and your lack of basic programming knowledge (which you should acquire before undertaking this task).

Answer (score 1):

If it is declared *via* `#define` then it is not a variable, it is a literal constant! Declare your `gameSize` as a (global) variable (outside any function) for example:

```
int gameSize;
```

Then through some interaction ('what kind of menu? GUI? Textual?, anyway...) let the user change it, example:

```
int main(...) {
  printf("Which game size would you like? "); // message on screen
  scanf("%d",&gameSize); // waiting for a number
  ...
}
```

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote. This answer (a) promotes the use of globals (b) sets the OP on the fast track to get a compiler error when their static arrays can't be instantiated with a global size variable.

Comment: Is under GUI menu. 
It has been declared as "define gameSize 3 ". It refers to 3x3 gamesize. 
I would like to change value of the gameSize in the main method.

Comment: In GUI, the trick is to have a callback in your code that is used to change the value of the game size, reinitializes the game board, etc and connected to some GUI element that let you select a value.

Comment: Sorry. Can you give me an example?

Comment: This may be another question... If you ask another, please let people know what language, what GUI, etc you use. And please post some code first (this means that you need to try something first by yourself).